# List comprehension for printing dump

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a list with huge amount of hex numbers. I want to print it in form of a dump (lets say 4 values in a line). I can do that with the following for loop:

```
#Trying to achieve this (printing values in lines of 3 from list):
for i,val in enumerate(my_list):
    if( i!=0 and i%3 == 0 ):
        print val
    else:
        print val,
```

I use the following list comprehension:

```
clist = [ val if i%3 == 0 else val, for i,val in enumerate(my_list) ]
print clist
```

This would give a syntax error. The error part I know is "val,". I know there would some difference is converting the above for loop into comprehension list than the way I usually do.
How should I convert the given for loop into a suitable comprehension list?

Comment: Why have you used `name` instead of `val` in `i,name in enumerate(my_list)`

Comment: oops, thats a typo, I will correct it

Comment: Is this the actual code giving the error? What does the error actually say?

Comment: `clist = [ val if i%3 == 0 else val, for i,val in enumerate(my_list) ]`
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Change `val, for` to `val for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a generator like this:

```
clist  = ( val+'' if (i+1)%3  else val+'\n' for i,val in enumerate(my_list) )
```

then print it like this:

```
for c in clist:
    print c,
```

--

edit:

if you don't want to iterate when printing, just prepare list and print it all at once:

```
clist = [val + (' ' if (i+1)%3 else '\n') for i,val in enumerate(my_list)]
print ''.join(clist)
```

Comment: Thnx a ton bro :)